# Does fewer bit representation of data improve training time of machine learning models?

Tags: performance, machine-learning

In a lot of notebooks on kaggle I see methods used to reduce memory usage of data, for example converting int64 columnns to int32.
Why do we want to reduce the memory usage if the data can fit in the memory? Does it make machine learning models train faster on the data ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. In a lot of models there will be numerous computations involving feature vectors.
For example in a MLP, we would do a weighted sum of the feature representations to produce output in each neuron .

Computations are much faster if feature vector components are 32 bit in comparison with 64 bit representations.

Let me illustrate with a simple example :

```py
import timeit

mult64 = """
import numpy as np
arr64 = np.int64([3,4,5])
arr64*arr64
"""

mult32 = """
import numpy as np
arr32 = np.int32([3,4,5])
arr32*arr32
"""

mult64_time = timeit.timeit(mult64, number=100)/100
mult32_time = timeit.timeit(mult32, number=100)/100

print(mult64_time)
print(mult32_time)
```

Gives me the result as below. As can be seen, the time taken to do a simple multiplication on CPU is way faster for int32 than int64. Have generally found this transformation useful to save training time/prediction time.

```
0.00086965738
1.7849500000000074e-06
```

Comment: @desertnaut `"""` is just multiline spanning string. Im executing these using timeit and averaging the time

Comment: Agreed, but  it is not reproducible like that; you could easily make it much more elegant and *directly reproducible* if you just use randomly generated numbers and avoid any references to not given data in a hypothetical external `sample-data.csv` file. I instinctively upvoted, but retracted when I realized that this is not reproducible. It's your answer of course to do what you want, I'm just saying...

Comment: @desertnaut Removed reference to the file, have hardcoded a numpy array with appropriate types to show the difference. Not sure what you mean by not reproducible.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - have never see Python code in such a style, but it is reproducible indeed. But, rather unsurprisingly, with only 3 numbers the time difference I get is much smaller than the one you show.

Comment: @desertnaut : That can really vary based on the system we run this on.